# Angular 8 native select returns [object object] on change event

Tags: angular, angular8, html-select

I have a native select to which I pass a list of custom objects. I pass as value to the options the entire object, and as description of the option I choose a property.
When the (change) event is fired I get a [object object] which I can't cast to my object or parse with JSON. It remains [object object] and I can't access its properties (they all return undefined).
[Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a4jees?file=src/app/app.component.ts).
Why can't I access my object?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select (change)="handleChangeSelectedOption()" [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option hidden disabled></option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.filiale"
   >
    {{ option.preselected}}
  </option>
</select>



  handleChangeSelectedOption() {
  alert(this.selected);
 }
```